How do I break when exception of type of Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException occurs
Usually I use try catch.
Then I look at the type of the exception caught.
Then I set that visual studio break on that exception.
But I can't use this technique anymore

Basically I want visual studio to break on exception of type newtonsoft.json
But there is no such thing

What should I do?

Can't you just add the condition ex.GetType() == type(    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException) (or the VB equivalent)?

I want it break exactly when the exception occurs not on the catch region. Anyway I caught the place where it happened.

Visual Studio has an "Exception" settings page, where all the common exceptions are listed and each of them can be configured to stop, when the exception occurred. You can add new exceptions to this list and click the checkbox that Visual Studio should stop on that exception.

Display the Exception Settings from Visual Studio.
Debug > Windows > Exception Settings
Select 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' and select the edit conditions button ✏️.

Press Add ➕
Enter the exception i.e. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException and hit enter.

